# как заставить объект двигаться назад C# Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
     void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        speed -= 0.5f;
        if (speed < -20)
        {
            speed = -20;
        }
```

не могу понять почему объект не идет назад где ощибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не указали, когда объект идет вперёд. Можно предположить что у вас управление на клавиши WASD, тогда назад должен идти персонаж на клавишу S

Посмотрим ваш код

Когда персонаж идет вперёд

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Тут всё правильно, transform.Translate - это команда для перемещения объекта. direction - направление, которое вы скорее всего указали ранее. Time.deltaTime - добавляется чтобы движение объекта было более плавным и не зависело от частоты кадров.

Посмотрим ваш код на букву S

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
{
    speed -= 0.5f;
    if (speed < -20)
    {
        speed = -20;
    }
}
```

Вы увеличиваете скорость, но нет кода самого движения объекта. И эта скорость, даже не используется в вашем движении вперёд. Правильный код будет такой

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
{
    transform.Translate(-direction * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Тоесть, точно такой же код как для движения вперёд. Но direction сделаем с минусом, так как нам нужно движение в ОБРАТНУЮ сторону от обычного направления. 
Т.е. Назад = -Вперёд. Запомните это правило, очень пригодится в программировании. Вниз = -Вверх, Право = -Лево и наоборот.

Comment: Чисто теоретически direction, обычно, - единичный вектор, который указывает направление, что вы и указали, но почему-то не использовали переменную `speed` вместе с вектором направления, что было бы "идеальным" ответом. Да и в ответе не хватает конечного "полного" кода, а не обрезков отдельных if'ов.